# how to join to files with awk/sed/grep/bash similar to SQL JOIN

Tags: linux, join, sed, awk, grep

**how to join to files with awk/sed/grep/bash similar to SQL JOIN?**

I have a file that looks like this:

[image]

and another one that looks like this:

[image]

i've also a text version of the image above:

```
+----------+------------------+------+------------+----+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+-----+-----+-----+------+-------+-------+--------------+------------+--+--+---+---+----+--+---+---+----+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 21548598 | DSND001906102.2  | 0107 |  001906102 | 02 | FROZEN / O.S.T.                                   | FROZEN / O.S.T.                                   | 001 | 024 |     |      | 11.49 | 13.95 | 050087295745 | 11/25/2013 |  |  | N | N | 30 |  | 1 | E |  1 | 10/07/2013 | 02/27/2014 | 10/07/2013 | 10/07/2013 |
| 25584998 | WD1194190DVD     | 0819 |    1194190 | 18 | FROZEN / (WS DOL DTS)                             | FROZEN / (WS DOL DTS)                             | 050 | 110 |     | G    | 21.25 | 29.99 | 786936838961 | 03/18/2014 |  |  | N | N |  0 |  | 1 | A |  2 | 12/20/2013 | 03/13/2014 | 12/20/2013 | 12/20/2013 |
| 25812794 | WHV1000292717BR  | 0526 | 1000292717 | BR | GRAVITY / (UVDC)                                  | GRAVITY / (UVDC)                                  | 050 | 093 |     | PG13 | 29.49 | 35.99 | 883929244577 | 02/25/2014 |  |  | N | N | 30 |  | 1 | E |  3 | 01/16/2014 | 02/11/2014 | 01/16/2014 | 01/16/2014 |
| 24475594 | SNY303251.2      | 0085 |     303251 | 02 | BEYONCE                                           | BEYONCE                                           | 001 | 004 |     |      | 14.99 | 17.97 | 888430325128 | 12/20/2013 |  |  | N | N | 30 |  | 1 | A |  4 | 12/19/2013 | 01/02/2014 | 12/19/2013 | 12/19/2013 |
| 25812787 | WHV1000284958DVD | 0526 | 1000284958 | 18 | GRAVITY (2PC) / (UVDC SPEC 2PK)                   | GRAVITY (2PC) / (UVDC SPEC 2PK)                   | 050 | 093 |     | PG13 | 21.25 | 28.98 | 883929242528 | 02/25/2014 |  |  | N | N | 30 |  | 1 | E |  5 | 01/16/2014 | 02/11/2014 | 01/16/2014 | 01/16/2014 |
| 21425462 | PBSDMST64400DVD  | E349 |      64400 | 18 | MASTERPIECE CLASSIC: DOWNTON ABBEY SEASON 4 (3PC) | MASTERPIECE CLASSIC: DOWNTON ABBEY SEASON 4 (3PC) | 050 | 095 | 094 |      | 30.49 | 49.99 | 841887019705 | 01/28/2014 |  |  | N | N | 30 |  | 1 | A |  6 | 09/06/2013 | 01/15/2014 | 09/06/2013 | 09/06/2013 |
| 25584974 | WD1194170BR      | 0819 |    1194170 | BR | FROZEN (2PC) (W/DVD) / (WS AC3 DTS 2PK DIGC)      | FROZEN (2PC) (W/DVD) / (WS AC3 DTS 2PK DIGC)      | 050 | 110 |     | G    | 27.75 | 39.99 | 786936838923 | 03/18/2014 |  |  | N | N |  0 |  | 2 | A |  7 | 12/20/2013 | 03/13/2014 | 01/15/2014 | 01/15/2014 |
| 21388262 | HBO1000394029DVD | 0203 | 1000394029 | 18 | GAME OF THRONES: SEASON 3                         | GAME OF THRONES: SEASON 3                         | 050 | 095 | 093 |      | 47.99 | 59.98 | 883929330713 | 02/18/2014 |  |  | N | N | 30 |  | 1 | E |  8 | 08/29/2013 | 02/28/2014 | 08/29/2013 | 08/29/2013 |
| 25688450 | WD11955700DVD    | 0819 |   11955700 | 18 | THOR: THE DARK WORLD / (AC3 DOL)                  | THOR: THE DARK WORLD / (AC3 DOL)                  | 050 | 093 |     | PG13 | 21.25 | 29.99 | 786936839500 | 02/25/2014 |  |  | N | N | 30 |  | 1 | A |  9 | 12/24/2013 | 02/20/2014 | 12/24/2013 | 12/24/2013 |
| 23061316 | PRT359054DVD     | 0818 |     359054 | 18 | JACKASS PRESENTS: BAD GRANDPA / (WS DUB SUB AC3)  | JACKASS PRESENTS: BAD GRANDPA / (WS DUB SUB AC3)  | 050 | 110 |     | R    | 21.75 | 29.98 | 097363590545 | 01/28/2014 |  |  | N | N | 30 |  | 1 | E | 10 | 12/06/2013 | 03/12/2014 | 12/06/2013 | 12/06/2013 |
| 21548611 | DSND001942202.2  | 0107 |  001942202 | 02 | FROZEN / O.S.T. (BONUS CD) (DLX)                  | FROZEN / O.S.T. (BONUS CD) (DLX)                  | 001 | 024 |     |      | 14.09 | 19.99 | 050087299439 | 11/25/2013 |  |  | N | N | 30 |  | 1 | E | 11 | 10/07/2013 | 02/06/2014 | 10/07/2013 | 10/07/2013 |
+----------+------------------+------+------------+----+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+-----+-----+-----+------+-------+-------+--------------+------------+--+--+---+---+----+--+---+---+----+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

The 2nd column from the first file can be joined to the 14th column of the second file!

here's what i've been trying to do:

```
join <(sort awk -F"\t" '{print $14,$12}' aecprda12.tab) <(sort awk -F"\t" '{print $2,$1}' output1.csv)
```

but i am getting these errors:

```
$ join <(sort awk -F"\t" '{print $14,$12}' aecprda12.tab) <(sort awk -F"\t" '{print $2,$1}' output1.csv) 
sort: unknown option -- F 
Try sort --help' for more information. 
sort: unknown option -- F 
Try sort --help' for more information. 
-700476409 [waitproc] -bash 10336 sig_send: error sending signal 20 to pid 10336, pipe handle 0x84, Win32 error 109
```

[image]

the output i would like would be something like this:

```
+-------+-------+---------------+
| 12.99 | 14.77 | 3383510002151 |
| 13.97 | 17.96 | 3383510002175 |
| 13.2  | 13    | 3383510002267 |
| 13.74 | 14.19 | 3399240165349 |
| 9.43  | 9.52  | 3399240165363 |
| 12.99 | 4.97  | 3399240165479 |
| 7.16  | 7.48  | 3399240165677 |
| 11.24 | 9.43  | 4011550620286 |
| 13.86 | 13.43 | 4260182980316 |
| 13.98 | 12.99 | 4260182980507 |
| 10.97 | 13.97 | 4260182980514 |
| 11.96 | 13.2  | 4260182980545 |
| 15.88 | 13.74 | 4260182980552 |
+-------+-------+---------------+
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could you simplify your "second file" - it is (almost) illegible and contains a lot of information we don't need to answer the question.

Comment: Please post the text of the error instead of a (tiny, illegible) image.

Comment: $ join <(sort awk -F"\t" '{print $14,$12}' aecprda12.tab) <(sort awk -F"\t" '{print $2,$1}' output1.csv)
sort: unknown option -- F
Try `sort --help' for more information.
sort: unknown option -- F
Try `sort --help' for more information.
-700476409 [waitproc] -bash 10336 sig_send: error sending signal 20 to pid 10336, pipe handle 0x84, Win32 error 109

Comment: The error says you are feeding `-F` to `sort`, when you mean to feed it to `awk`. Did you miss a pipe symbol in your command between `sort` and `awk`, perhaps?

Comment: @Floris to answer your first question, yes i simplified it just now

Comment: `sort awk ....` makes no sense. Probably should be `awk ... | sort`, or `sort <(awk ...)`

Answer (score 6):

You can do all the work in `join` and `sort`

```
join -1 2 -2 14 -t $'\t' -o 2.12,1.1,0 \
     <( sort -t $'\t' -k 2,2   output1.csv ) \
     <( sort -t $'\t' -k 14,14 aecprda12.tab )
```

Notes:

- `$'\t'` is a bash [ANSI-C quoted](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) string which is a tab character: neither join nor sort seem to recognize the 2-character string `"\t"` as a tab
- `-k col,col` sorts the file on the specified column
- join has several options to control how it works; see the [join(1)](http://man.cx/join) man page.

Comment: what is this? -o 2.12,1.1,0

Answer (score 1):

```
sort awk -F...
```

is not a valid command; it means sort a file named `awk` but of course, like the error message says, there is no `-F` option to `sort`. The syntax you are looking for is

```
awk -F ... | sort
```

However, you might be better off doing the joining in Awk directly.

```
awk -F"\t" 'NR==FNR{k[$14]=$12; next}
    k[$2] { print $2, $1, k[$2] }' aecprda12.tab output1.csv
```

Comment: thank you very much. im new to this could you please provide the full statement that i woudl use?

Comment: i thought that in linux every statement produces a "file", such as "awk -F"\t" '{print $14,$12}' aecprda12.tab"  should be producing a file, and since sort ... expects a file, i thought that it would be appropriate

Comment: This is a frequently asked question and a common idiom; google for `NR==FNR`.

Comment: @tripleee - I ended up with essentially the same code as you (although I started with the first file and you started with the second…). Had not seen yours when I wrote mine.

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' if you want to use output of one command as a file in another command, you can use something like `sort <(awk ...)` (I haven't tested this particular case though).

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you don't know whether every item in the first file has a corresponding item in the second file - and that you want only "matching" items. There is indeed a good way to do this in awk. Create the following script (as a text file, call it `myJoin.txt`):

```
BEGIN {
  FS="\t"
}
# loop around as long as the total number of records read
# is equal to the number of records read in this file
# in other words - loop around the first file only
NR==FNR {
  a[$2]=$1 # create one array element for each $1/$2 pair
  next
}
# loop around all the elements of the second file:
# since we're done processing the first file
{
  # see if the associative array element exists:
  gsub(/ /,"",$14) # trim leading/ trailing spaces
  if (a[$14]) { # see if the value in $14 was seen in the first file
    # print out the three values you care about:
    print $12 " " a[$14] " " $14
  }
}
```

Now execute this with

```
awk -f myJoin.txt file1 file2
```

Seems to work for me...